# What is the correct verb when a company stops using services from another company?

Tags: word-choice, word-request, verbs

Lets say a company was using another company's services, but decided to move away to a different company. What is the correct verb for that?

I've looked in the dictionary for antonyms of cooperation but most of them didn't feel right. For example, if I use disjoint it seems like they were working together.

Should I use unsubscribe?

Comment: No, **unsubscribe** has a far more specific meaning. Also, you must decide whether you wish to speak about the relationship/partnership between the two companies, or about the services provided.  You can end a relationship and discontinue services.

Comment: Most of the answers thus far are focusing on verbs for leaving the first company. If you're looking for a verb that encompasses both parts of the transaction, you could consider **migrate**, as in: _It seems there are a million and one tutorials on how to [migrate](http://robfine.com/migrateoutlookcomemailstogmail) your email from Gmail to Outlook, but instructions for migrating the other way are not as easy to find;_ or, _Netflix billing [migration](https://medium.com/netflix-techblog/netflix-billing-migration-to-aws-451fba085a4) to AWS_.

Comment: @J.R., I think you comment should be an answer.

Comment: When a customer leaves us, we use the term "deconvert".  No, it doesn't make sense to me either.

Comment: I would suggest "transfer": "We are transferring our advertizing account from XYZ to ABC."

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Terminate comes to mind

> We have decided to terminate (our use of) your services

And the provider can respond

> You have successfully terminated your use of our services
>
> On your request, we have discontinued our services

Comment: "discontinue" is a good phrasing even for the request. "We have decided to discontinue using your services," or "We can no longer continue using your services."

Comment: Relationship is also handy the thing being terminated. "We have terminated our relationship with ACME."

Answer (score 3):

In colloquial usage, you can **fire** (American English) or **sack** (British English) a supplier or business partner, just as you can fire or sack (i.e. terminate the employment of) an employee.

[How to fire a supplier](https://www.trustbase.com/blog/how-to-fire-a-supplier.html)

[How to sack your IT supplier](https://www.computerworld.com/article/2518672/it-management/how-to-sack-your-it-supplier.html)

Answer (score 2):

Both "canceling" and "cancellation" could work, depending on the context. As in cancelling an active service, such as internet, shipping, electricity, etc., or the cancellation of a contract.

Answer (score 1):

How about disengage, or dissociate (can also be written as disassociate)?

More passive than terminate, if that was what was required?